# How i can send it to specific link when some swipe to unlock

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello Everyone I need help with this coding as I want to make someone to visit on specific page when they swipe to unlock and when swipe end the person should automatically be transfer to specific page.

Please Help Thank You

```js
$(function () {
    $('.opened').hide();
    $('.closed').draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        containment: 'parent',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left > 230) {
            }
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left < 230) {
                $(this).animate({ left: 17 });
            }
            if (ui.position.left < 15) {
                $(this).animate({ left: 17 });
            }
            if (ui.position.left > 230) {
                $(this).animate({ left: 230 }, function () {
                    $(this).hide().animate({ left: 17 });
                    $('.opened').show();
                    $('.padlock-loop').addClass('padlock-open');
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $('.opened').draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        containment: 'parent',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left < 5) {
            }
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left > 15) {
                $(this).animate({ left: 230 });
            }
            if (ui.position.left > 230) {
                $(this).animate({ left: 230 });
            }
            if (ui.position.left < 15) {
                $(this).animate({ left: 17 }, function () {
                    $(this).hide().animate({ left: 230 });
                    $('.closed').show();
                    $('.padlock-loop').removeClass('padlock-open');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
//@ sourceURL=pen.js
```

```css
body {
  background: #5b8052;
  font-family: "helvetica neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.padlock {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -125px;
  margin-left: -30px;  
}

.padlock-loop {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border-top: 6px solid #4D7046;
  border-left: 6px solid #4D7046;
  border-right: 6px solid #4D7046;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

.padlock-open {
  top: 0;
}

.padlock-body {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 44px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #4D7046;
}

.padlock:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  width: 6px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 36px;
  background: #4D7046;
}

.padlock-body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 26px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background: #3A5933;
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

.padlock-body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 24px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #3A5933;
  
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -140px;
  background: #496942;
  /*background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#507348), to(#5b8052));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #507348, #5b8052); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #507348, #5b8052);
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #507348, #5b8052);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #507348, #5b8052);*/
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.slider-shape {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  overflow: hidden;  
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 2px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);*/
}


.open {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 65px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -120px;
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider-circle {
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  background: #5b8052;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);*/
  cursor: move;
}

.closed {
  position: absolute;
  left: 17px;
}

.opened {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html class=''>
<head><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name="robots" content="noindex"><link rel="canonical" href="http://codepen.io/waylaid/pen/BKIkj" />

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
</head><body>
<div class="padlock">
  <span class="padlock-loop"></span>
  <span class="padlock-body"></span>
</div>
  
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slider-shape">
    
    <div class="slider-circle closed">
      <span class="open">Slide to unlock</span>
      <span class="close">Slide to lock</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slider-circle opened">
      <span class="open">Slide to unlock</span>
      <span class="close">Slide to lock</span>
    </div>  
    
  </div>  
</div>
<script src='//assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout.js?t=1'></script><script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='//codepen.io/assets/editor/live/css_live_reload_init.js'></script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give like following:

```
if (ui.position.left > 230) {
                $(this).animate({ left: 230 }, function () {
                  window.open("page2.html");
                    $(this).hide().animate({ left: 17 });
                    $('.opened').show();
                    $('.padlock-loop').addClass('padlock-open');

                });
```

You can give path of new page which you want to open instead of "page2.html".

Another way to open the page are:

```
window.location.href = "page2.html"
```

Or

```
$(this).load("page2.html");
```

Comment: @GarrySahota I think for that you need to use iframe.